# Java MySQL Webapp - Query shows just one entry?

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications

Hello my Code shows just one entry! Someone can help me?

This is the Main part of the Code:

```
        DatabaseHandler worker = new DatabaseHandler();     
    
    String query = "select standort, sum(einnahmen) as ein, sum(ausgaben) as aus from biointeractive.standorte";
    
    try {
           Statement statement = worker.getConnection().createStatement();
           ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
                       
           while(resultSet.next()){
           
           String stand = resultSet.getString("standort");
           int ein = resultSet.getInt("ein");
           int aus = resultSet.getInt("aus");
           int bil = ein + aus;
           
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("<html><body><hr></br><h1>Standort: </h1>" + stand + "</br><h1>Einnahmen: </h1>" + ein + "</br><h1>Ausgaben: </h1>"
                    + aus + "</br><h1>Bilanz: </h1>" + bil + "</br><hr></body></html>");
           }
```

Comment: for all we know, there is only one response. why do you create a new PrintWriter each iteration?

Comment: So how is it maybe possible to show all entries?

Comment: So the Print writer should be before the while?

Comment: for all we know, that query just returns one. and yes, there is no need whatsoever to create a new one each time.

Comment: So the query returns just one response because of there is the sum function right?

Comment: I don't know whether or not it returns just one. You should check that. you need only one writer. as dssjoblom states, you should have only one <html> </html> root

Comment: Okay I will check it.

Comment: So it is because of Suming, if I try it without and just select standort, than it works!

Answer (score 0):

Besides other issues mentioned, you are also writing multiple `<html/>` tags. Maybe the site doesn't display correctly in the browser, check the HTML source?

Comment: So I should put the html tag before while loop, too right?